# VSTS Role to change the backlog item status

Tags: azure-devops

Colleagues,

Is there any way in VSTS I can only allow the project owner to change the backlog item status to "Approved" for instance?

On the dashboard, I also implemented a custom step called "Resolved", assuming that once user story/feature is done, only QA can move it further to "Done" (after relevant testing).

Is it possible to restrict the access to the QA guy only (I mean the status change from "Resolved" to "Done")?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Work item editing is all-or-nothing.